# Redirect page when URL parameter not set

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to redirect a page if there is a missing url parameter. I have found the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669336/redirect-if-wordpress-query-string-is-empty):

```
function redirect_to_pending($query) {

    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_page(26)) {

        if(!array_key_exists('shazzid', $query->query_vars) || empty(get_query_var('shazzid'))) {

            wp_redirect(get_permalink(1752));
            exit;
        }  
    }
}
add_action('parse_query', 'redirect_to_pending');
```

It seems to work perfectly on any page except the homepage, where it generates the following error `Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3956`

Answer (score 1):

However, to solve the issue, it seems the answer is to check the queried object is not NULL `$query->get_queried_object() !== NULL`

I had to remove the query_var because it turned the homepage into a 404. A separate issue.

```
// redirect if there's no job id
function redirect_to_pending($query) {

    if($query->get_queried_object() !== NULL && $query->is_page(26)) {

        if(!isset($_GET['shazzid'])) {

            wp_redirect(get_permalink(1752));
            exit;
        }  
    }
}
add_action('parse_query', 'redirect_to_pending');
```